# Clip raster to polygons in sf collection [R sf]

Tags: r, polygon, raster, r-sf, clip

I would like to clip a raster using a simple feature collection of polygons, so that I end up with as many raster clips as there are polygons in my sf collection. Then I would like to save each raster clip as a jpg. Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(sf)
library(raster)
austria1 <- getData('GADM', country='AUT', level=1)
austria1 <- st_as_sf(austria1)
climate <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=2.5)
```

I would like to clip climate to the nine polygons in austria1, so I end up with 9 raster clips. Then I would like to save those 9 raster clips as jpg files in my working directory.

Thanks for any help!

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example data

```
library(sf)
library(raster)
austria <- getData('GADM', country='AUT', level=1)
austria <- st_as_sf(austria)
climate <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=2.5)
climate <- climate[[1]]  # just the first layer
```

A for loop

```
for (i in 1:nrow(austria)) {
    a <- austria1[i, ]
    fn <- tolower(paste0(a$NAME_1, ".jpg"))
    print(fn); flush.console()
    x <- crop(climate, a)
    y <- mask(x, a)
    jpeg(fn)       
    plot(y)
    dev.off()
}
```

You will probably want to improve the jpgs by changing some default arguments to `jpeg`

Comment: Hi Robert. This works really well, thanks for your help! For a larger dataset (e.g., tens of thousands of raster clips) I'm wondering if this could be accomplished without a loop to speed things up, e.g. using the apply() family of functions. Do you have thoughts on that? Thanks again.

Comment: Robert, as a followup question, what does the mask() command do in your answer? I've examined a few results with and without that line, and I can't tell what it's doing.